# Are thread_local objects initialized to 0 in C?

Tags: c, initialization, language-lawyer, thread-local-storage

Are non-local thread storage duration objects initialized to 0 in C?

```
static thread_local int x; // is x initialized to 0?
```

The C17 standard says the below (in 6.2.4.4).

> An object whose identifier is declared with the storage-class specifier _Thread_local has thread
> storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the thread for which it is created, and its
> *stored value is initialized* when the thread is started.

It does not explicitly say it is initialized to 0. But the C++
standard makes it explicit and says: (in 3.6.2.2)

> Variables with static storage duration ([basic.stc.static]) or thread
> storage duration ([basic.stc.thread]) shall be zero-initialized
> ([dcl.init]) before any other initialization takes place

So, does C initialize non-local thread_local objects to 0 or not?

Comment: It is also explicit in C standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks! Can you just post it as an answer so that I accept it?

Comment: Why was this tagged [atomic] [stdatomic] but not [thread-local-storage]?  Did you mean to mention `_Atomic` and `stdatomic.h`?  I fixed the tags to match the current question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread local objects without explicit initialization are initialized to “zero.”

C 2018 7.26.1 3 says `thread_local` expands to `_Thread_local` if `<threads.h>` is included. That is not shown in the question, but presumably it is.

C 2018 6.2.4 4 says “An object whose identifier is declared with the storage-class specifier `_Thread_local` has *thread storage duration*…

C 2018 6.7.9 10 says:

> … If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

The paragraph ends there; the trailing “;” instead of a period is a typographical error.